# Django UserProfile Forms

Tags: python, django

I have a Django form that allows a user to save their UserProfile details, but it only allows this to occur once. Given that additional saves ask to create a new entry, but i have a one-to-one relation between the user field and user UserProfile field.

When a user is created a UserProfile entry is not created. Rather they cannot access their account until these details are filled out.

I want to pre-populate the form with existing data when a student goes to access the form a second time.

```
def student_details(request):
    #this is a form
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DetailsForm(request.user, request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                note = form.save(commit=False)
                note.user = request.user
                note.completed_form = True
                note.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/student-portal/')
        else:
            if request.user.get_profile():
                pass
                form = DetailsForm(request.user)
            else:
                form = DetailsForm(request.user)
        return render_to_response("student-details.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys just found out how to do this:

```
def student_details(request):
    #this is a form
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DetailsForm(request.user, request.POST, request.FILES)

            if form.is_valid():
                note = form.save(commit=False)
                user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
                if user_profile:
                    note.id = user_profile.id
                note.user = request.user
                note.completed_form = True
                note.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/student-portal/')
        else:
            try:
                user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
                form = DetailsForm(request.user, instance=user_profile)
            except:
                form = DetailsForm(request.user)
        return render_to_response("student-details.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

The idea here is to query to see if a user_profile linked to that user already exists and then specify the ID for that entry.